Identify mecha anime from the 80s/Early 90's, chosen ones
So, I watched this anime around 1995-1997. It was from the 80's/early 90's. Giant mecha were involved.
The plot is as follows:

one of the characters, an old witch, is trying to find the chosen ones, destined to pilot giant robots and fight evil. They are 3 boys. The way to summon the robots is via 3 magical items which chosen ones wield.
She has a daughter/granddaughter which also has magical powers. The memorable scene is the little girl saying magical words and her whole room lighting on fire causing one of the chosen ones to panic. When he gets back, the room is ok. (edit: this happens in first episode)
Giant robots are connected to elements Water, Air and Earth (not sure about fire)
One of the robots is summoned by the chosen one using whip to spin a  whirligig, either on water or ground, which makes a geometrical pattern/summoning circle on the surface. Giant robot gets out of that circle then gets back once the fight is over.
Edit: Thanks for the answer, it was Mado King Grandzort. Whirligig summoning scene :). It wasn't whip but a gun.  The water one was summoned with a whip whirligig!








The second robot is summoned by shooting a magical bow through the air, it makes also a magical circle then the giant robot guardian of air shows up. It is extremely hard to notch that bow and pull the bowstring
The third is summoned by some sword, I think by also drawing a magical pattern. That's all I remember.


EDIT: NEW ANSWER
Could it be Granzort?
I read in Wikipedia the following characteristics which I'll point out that seems to cross very well with your description:

There is a witch with a granddaughter
There are boys summoning elemental mechas
One of them summon with a bow
Although one of the other boys summons with a gun, and the other with a top

Here is a picture:


OLD ANSWER
Are you sure they were boys? Because this sounds A LOT like Magic Knight Rayearth.

It ran between 1994-1995
It had three chosen girls with three different elements (Fire, Water, Earth)
The Fire one has a sword
The Water I'm not sure if she has a whip
The Air one has a bow
They are destined to pilot mechas of each of their elements

All of them starts with different weapons that then evolve into a sword.
Here is a picture:

But as you may see, the air girl starts with a bow:


RayEarth was my first thought for this question, too, but I discounted it because of the "boys" thing.  Here's hoping it was just a mis-remembering by the OP!

@Steve-O Exactly. At first I'm just guessing it is just a fake memory. Sometimes these are mixed scenes from different shows that we remember as one. So, I'll just keep hoping for now. Haha..

Sorry guys, it's not it. I really hopped it was Magic Knight Rayearth. I even watched the first episode and watch-skipped over the next three. It looks pretty similar, I agree, but it is not the one. I'll try to see if I remember more details. Sounds like nice show, anyway. Haven't heard of it before.

@jo1storm Check my new answer!

Yes, that's it. Mado King Grandzort. Thank you so much! The one that summons with a gun, the bullet is shaped like a whirligig and spins on the ground to summon the robot. Thank you.

@jo1storm No problem, man! :)
